# IO-функции в kernel-space

Tags: macos, kernel

Env.: macOS, пишу драйвер, компилятор - clang

---

Пытаюсь использовать ф-ию `write`, подключаю хэдер `unistd.h` - компилятор выдает ошибку - файл не найден. Указываю в настройках проекта дополнительный путь, где искать хэдеры - */usr/include* - компилятор выдает бесчисленное количество ошибок самого разного содержания. С чем это связано? Я не могу в kernel-space использовать `write`? Или я должен использовать какие-то другие ф-ии?

Comment: Вполне логично, что для вызова userspace функции придется делать ряд дополнительных манипуляций. И вполне логично, что для такой базовой функции, как write есть какой-то аналог для использования в kernel space.

Comment: @VTT, да, спасибо, это верное направление ) Просто я до сего момента ни разу не писал что-то в kernel-space что связано с вводом-выводом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не уверен, что это единственный доступный способ, но он рабочий:

```
vnode_t       vnode = NULLVP;
vfs_context_t ctxt = vfs_context_create(0);
errno_t       errno;

errno = vnode_open(file_name_buf, (O_TRUNC | O_CREAT | O_RDWR), S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR, VNODE_LOOKUP_NOFOLLOW, &vnode, ctxt);
if (!errno) {
    vn_rdwr(UIO_WRITE
        , vnode
        , buffer 
        , buf_inf.bytesused
        , 0
        , UIO_SYSSPACE
        , IO_NOCACHE | IO_NODELOCKED | IO_UNIT
        , vfs_context_ucred(ctxt)
        , (int*)0
        , vfs_context_proc(ctxt));

    vnode_close(vnode, FWASWRITTEN, ctxt);
}
```

Вместо `vfs_context_create(0)` можно использовать `vfs_context_current()`.